# Ruby State Machine with history, superstates, and logs/statistics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine, aasm

Is there any state machine implementation for Ruby or Ruby on Rails that supports [superstates](http://blog.8thlight.com/articles/2007/4/7/understanding-statemachines-part-4-superstates), can keep track of past states (and edit them), and keep track of the time spent on each state?

I've used [aasm](https://github.com/rubyist/aasm) but it doesn't have all these features. I've looked at many other options but it's not clear which one might best support all of the requirements. Has anyone used aasm with [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) in such a manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably already looked at it, but http://slagyr.github.com/statemachine/index.html seems to be the gem to use with state machines these days, and it does support superstates.

edit: and the article you've linked to uses statemachine.. silly me